# How would I secure a pex shut off valve to the stud in the wall interior?

Tags: plumbing, valve, pex

This **3/4 in. Brass PEX Barb x Barb Ball Valve** will be my main shut off valve in my house. It will be in an interior wall behind a wall panel.

How can I secure this valve within the wall so it doesn't move around when the valve is turned on & off?

[image]
[image]

Comment: what the hell is that guy doing in the photo?  He is holding backwards. it goes with  the flat part out.

Answer (score 2):

Generally you would just secure the PEX with some pipe clams near the valve and that would be good enough. The valve just hangs there in mine and I usually grab a pipe with one hand when I turn it.

Comment: This seems avoidably prone to stressing the barb fitting attachment to the PEX. Maybe not an issue for valves which are rarely used.

Comment: If you're worried about the valve shifting you could brace it with wood alongside.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a "drop-ear" valve, which would look like this:

[image]

The "ears" are meant for mounting the valve with screws.